# Show that a surjective function from $X$ to $J$ does not exist (with a twist!!)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that

> Suppose that $X$ is a set and $f:X\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ is any function, then $f$ is not
>   surjective.

But what if there are two sets $X$ and $Y$, and set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ is called $J$.

**So how would I show that there is no surjective function
from $X$ to $J$**

Answer (score 3):

There are a few of cases that have to be handled separately:

- If $X = \emptyset$, then there is exactly one function $X \to Y$ for any $Y$ (which happens to be the empty function, $\emptyset$). Clearly there is no surjection $\emptyset \to \{ \emptyset \}$.
- If $X \neq \emptyset$ and $Y = \emptyset$, then there are no functions $X \to Y$, and there are no functions $X \to J$ since $J = \emptyset$.
- If $X \neq \emptyset$ and $|Y| = 1$, then there is exactly one function $X \to Y$ (the constant function). In this case there will always be a surjection $X \to J$.
- If $X \neq \emptyset$ and $|Y| > 1$, then pick distinct $y_0,y_1 \in Y$ and define a function $\varphi : \mathcal{P}(X) \to J$ so that for any $A \subseteq X$, $\varphi (A) ( x ) = y_0$ if $x \in A$ and $\varphi (A) ( x ) = y_1$ if $x \notin A$. This is an injection, showing $| \mathcal{P}(X) | \leq |J|$. It follows that if there were a surjection $X \to J$, there would also be a surjection $X \to \mathcal{P} (X)$, which we know is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $J$, let's use the established notation ${}^XY$ for the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$.  The statement you're trying to prove is false in the degenerate case where $|X| > 0$ and $|Y| < 2$.  Here we'll have $|{}^XY| = |Y| \leq |X|$.

Otherwise, however, the statement is true:  If $|X| = 0$ and $|Y| < 2$, then $|{}^XY| = 1 > 0 = |X|$, so there is no surjection $X \to {}^XY$.  The remaining case, which is the interesting case, is where $|Y| \geq 2$.  You can use the fact that $|Y| \geq 2$ to show that, if there's a surjection $X\to {}^YX$, then there's a surjection $X\to\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: But does the last case go against what I am trying to prove (no surjective function)?

Comment: Established notation? I've always seen $Y^X$ instead.

Comment: In the last case (where $|Y|\geq 2$), the statement is true.

Comment: @Marc Some people prefer this one. In particular, if you work with cardinals (which are themselves sets), you would not be able to distinguish whether $\alpha^\beta$ means the set of all sets from $\beta$ to $\alpha$ or its cardinal. (But I have seen many people using your notation - and the distinction between the two meanings is usually clear from context.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can write $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as set of all functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$ which I use as a standard 2 element set. So let me write $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as $\textrm{Map}(X,\{0,1\})$

If $Y$ is any set having more than 2 elements then you can consider $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as a subset of $\textrm{Map}(X,Y)$ by pretending two elements of $Y$ as 0 and 1 and then composing by any map from $Y$ to $\{0,1\}$. Also note that this operation from $\textrm{Map}(X,Y)$ to $\textrm{Map}(X,\{0,1\})$ is surjective.

so if $\phi:X\rightarrow\textrm{Map}(X,Y)$ is surjective you can produce a surjection from $X$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$

The above obviously fails if cardinality of Y is less than 2.